# Comparator<? super T> as functions parameter- how use?

Tags: java, comparator

I'm beginner. I have to implement a method for finding min and max elements of a stream in accordance with a given comparator. If the stream doesn't contain any elements, invoke:

```
minMaxConsumer.accept(null, null);
```

I can't invoke:

```
minMaxConsumer.accept(test.min(order), test.max(order));
```

code:

```
public static <T> void findMinMax(
    Stream<? extends T> stream,
    Comparator<? super T> order,
    BiConsumer<? super T, ? super T> minMaxConsumer) {
        Stream<T> test = Stream.concat(Stream.empty(),stream);
        if(test.count()==0)
        {
            minMaxConsumer.accept(null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            minMaxConsumer.accept(test.min(order), test.max(order));
        }
    }
```

error:

```
Compilation error
Main.java:12: error: incompatible types: Optional<T> cannot be converted to CAP#1
            minMaxConsumer.accept(test.min(order), test.max(order));
```

Answer (score 4):

unwrap the optional. `test.min(X)` does not return a T; it returns an `Optional<T>`. As in, it returns the notion: There is either precisely one value, or there is no value. The no value case occurs for empty streams, of course.

Note, this code doesn't work in any case even if you fix this; the count() operation is 'terminal'. It consumes the stream. Therefore, given that you run a count operation first, the stream is consumed and it is not possible to run min or max ops. Aside from that, you can't first run min, and then max (because these too are terminal operations and running either one means the other one has no elements to look at anymore).

Comment: Should I create stream for min and another stream for max?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findMinMax(
                () -> IntStream.range(1, 100).boxed(),
                new NumberComparator(),
                (min, max) -> System.out.println("Min : "+  min + " Max " + max)
        );
    }

    public static <T> void findMinMax(
            Supplier<Stream<? extends T>> stream,
            Comparator<? super T> comparator,
            BiConsumer<? super T, ? super T> minMaxConsumer) {
        T min = stream.get().min(comparator).orElse(null);
        T max = stream.get().max(comparator).orElse(null);
        minMaxConsumer.accept(min, max);
    }

    static class NumberComparator implements Comparator<Number> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Number o1, Number o2) {
            return Double.compare(o1.doubleValue(), o2.doubleValue());
        }
    }
```

It uses a supplier for the stream in order to create two instances of the stream.